# Binding colors to ListPicker

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-7.1, listpicker

I'm trying to make a ListPicker control that contains a list of levels, with a colored square next to each level. This is what I've got:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="LevelList"
                    Header="Level"
                    ItemCountThreshold="0"
                    FontFamily="Segoe WP Light">
  <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}"
                   Width="43"
                   Height="43" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   Margin="12 0 0 0" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
  <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                  Margin="16 21 0 20">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding}"
                   Width="43"
                   Height="43" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   Margin="16 0 0 0"
                   FontSize="43"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

and in the c# part, I have

```
    String[] Level= { "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5"};
    String[] colors = { "#FFE5AD1B", "#FF0050EF", "#FFE51400", "#FF008A00", "#FFAA00FF" };

    public TolonPk()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        this.listaNivel.ItemsSource = Level;
        this.listaNivel.ItemsSource = colors;
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to bind the Textblock strictly to the Level String array and the rectangle fill to the colors...
I'm probably missing something simple, but I just can't seem to get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if toolkit:ListPicker uses its ItemsSource like other WPF ItemsControl subclasses, then you need to have both the Level string and the Color string in the same list.

Make a little struct/class that contains a string for level and a string for color.

```
public struct LevelAndColor
{
    public String Level { get; set; }
    public String Color { get; set; }
}
```

Create some IEnumerable (List, ObservableCollection, etc.) and populate it with your instances of level-color pairs.

In the binding, bind like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="43" Height="43"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}" Margin="12 0 0 0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Ok I get the creating the struct, i think, but where am I supposed to crate the array and populate it?